# How to select Columns using parameters in report builder

Tags: sql-server, select, reporting-services, parameters, reportbuilder3.0

In report builder can we select columns using parameters.

Example : `select @field, column2, column3 from table_name`

where `@field` is a parameter.

Also is there any way to do this:

```
select @field, column2, sum(column3) OVER (PARTITION BY @field)  from table_name
```

Comment: To select it, it should work fine when defined as a query datasource. To partition by it, you need a dynamic query.

Comment: In any solution you may find, you will need to add an alias for the column name, in order to have a static reference for the column in your report e.g. `SELECT @field AS myfield`

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done using dynamic sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE COLUMNRETURN
@ColumnName as nvarchar(100)
as
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'Select [' + @ColumnName + '] from [mytable]'
exec (@sql)

EXEC COLUMNRETURN 'mycolumn'
```

Comment: can I use this in report builder 3.0 also?

Comment: I do not know. This is T-SQL.